# How do I define a C struct containing a char that has a set size (for dynamic arrays)?

Tags: c

How do I define a struct containing a char that has a set size (for dynamic arrays)?

Comment: There's some confusion between "set size" and "dynamic". How do you want to set the size of this field?

Comment: I suspect that "a set size" does not mean the same thing to most of us as it does to you.  It would help if you described in more detail how you would like to use your struct type.  Perhaps it would also be useful if you presented a hypothetical syntax for what you want.

Comment: A `char` always has a fixed size. Do you mean `char` array instead?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [a flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)?

Answer (score 0):

In C everything should have a fixed size if you don't make variable-length arrays (arrays declared with a length which is not a `const int` nor a literal).

So assuming the question "How do I define a struct which has a set size and contains a char array", the following answers would work :

```
struct mystruct {
    char c[256];
};
/* sizeof(struct mystruct) == 256 */
```

With strings allocated somewhere else :

```
struct mystruct {
    char *c; 
};
/* sizeof(struct mystruct) == 8 */
```

Note that with the first answer there is a limit on the maximum length of the strings, and on the minimum amount of memory allocated.